# https url not found on ubuntu apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl

Trying the configure SSL on Apache2 on Ubuntu server installed Apache

```
sudo apt install apache2
Opened ufw firewall
sudo ufw allow 'Apache'
ufw allow https
```

Installed SSL files in /root/cert

```
  chmod 400 /root/cert/*
  chmod 500 /root/cert/
```

In /etc/apache2/sites-available fhttp://www.domainnname.com

```
Error:
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.     Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.     Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 443
```

https://www.domainnname.com

```
Error:
Not found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at green-synapse.com Port 443
```

http://localhost

```
shows domain wordpress website correctly
```

https://localhost

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

default-ssl.conf is configured

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname/index.html
The index.html file exists
```

configured 000-default.conf

```
ServerName domainname.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname/index.html
```

configured domainname.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@domainname.com
    Servername domainname.com
ServerAlias domainname.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname/index.html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@domainname.com
    Servername domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.green-synapse.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname/index.html
# SSL
    SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/domain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cert/ca_bundle.crt

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

wordpress.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/wordpress
 <Directory /srv/www/wordpress>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
 <Directory /srv/www/wordpress/wp-content>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/wordpress
 <Directory /srv/www/wordpress>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
 <Directory /srv/www/wordpress/wp-content>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
        SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/domainname.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/domainname.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cert/ca_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

sudo systemctl status apache2.service -l --no-pager

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-11-14 12:47:10 CST; 9h ago
……
Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 14 12:47:10 gs2023 apachectl[30239]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/green-synapse/index.html] does not exist
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/green-synapse/index.html] does not exist
 Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I want https://domainname to show the wordpress site just like http://localhost correctly displays the wordpress website

Comment: *"when I perform `https://localhost` the website comes up. However when I perform `https://localhost` then it gives error ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR."* - aren't these contradictory statements? At first you say that the site comes up, then you say that you get an error - for exactly the same URL of `https://localhost` in both cases. In any way, check the servers error log.

Comment: it was a typo, edited original posting. http works, https gives error. /var/log/apache2/server log contents: ::1 - - [12/Nov/2023:14:33:18 -0600] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 510 "https://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
<server_ip> - - [12/Nov/2023:14:33:33 -0600] "-" 408 0 "-" "-"

Comment: That's the access log not the error log of the server. But based on your edit - it is not clear which of the configs apply. But you have defined two VirtualHost on *:443. one with certificates and the other without. You should have only one, and this with certificates. Also, if you access the site with the name `localhost` this need to be reflected both in the config and also in the certificate.

Comment: I disabled firewall with sudo ufw disable. I used incognito mode from Safari Browser(outside the server), and tried to access http://www.domainname.com, it gives error: safari can't connect to the server, safari can't open the page https://localhost because safari can't connect to the server 'localhost'
It is getting redirected to from http domain name to https localhost and failing.

Comment: SSL installed and sudo netstat -anp | grep apache2 shows
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      909/apache2         
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      909/apache2
Also I deleted virtualhost 443 from wordpress.conf, I left virtualhost 80 and 443 on domainname.conf file

Comment: @Stefen Ullrich I updated the original posting with error log. It says you configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) . This may be error. If it is, I dont know how to fix it?

Comment: is it me or your forgot to declare the 3 SSLCertificate* parameters in your `<VirtualHost *:443>` in wordpress.conf?

Comment: @pataluc In what format should I insert the 3 ssl statements in wordpress.conf file? I thought my domainname.conf file should have it.

Comment: The answer did not work for me. I dont know how the system assigned 50 points to the answer. I have not accepted it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf file with the following, rebooted, and Apache is listening on port 443.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
            DocumentRoot /srv/www/wordpress
            ServerName www.domain.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/domianname.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/domainname.com.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3 SSL configuration parameters:

```
SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/domain.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cert/ca_bundle.crt
```

Have to appear in your `<VirtualHost *:443>` in wordpress.conf also.

Because of the `ServerName www.domainname.com` parameter, the Virtualhost in domainname.conf is used only if you access your webserver via http://www.domainname.com, and not if you use http://localhost.

I think it is the root cause of your ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

**EDIT:**

I think you should remove (or move away to disable it) your domainname.conf file.

Then, in wordpress.conf:

- add `Servername domainname.com` after both `Virtualhost` lines (not sure if mandatory)
- change the port of the 2nd Virtualhost to 443
- add `SSLEngine on` before `SSLCertificateFile` line

then try to access https://localhost from your server or https://domainname.com from your "browser outside the server"

It should be better.

Comment: I did it, does not work https://domainname, says not found, Started a bounty

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I misunderstood your problem, I thought you wanted to get rid of the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, which I thought my answer could help.
As for accessing your wordpress through https://domainname.com, it would require to change the `DocumentRoot` in domainname.conf...

Comment: I edited my answer. Your `You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port` is caused because there is no `SSLEngine on` on the targeted virtualhost

Comment: SSL is running on the host, since there is no ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. after reinstalling apache2 and reconfig default-ssl.conf. When I go locahost it is working by picking the right wordpress files. When I go https from outside, how come it says not found.

Comment: SSL is running no the host, true, but has to be activated on each Virtualhost.
cf https://serverfault.com/questions/744960/configuring-ssl-with-virtual-hosts-under-apache-and-centos and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7

Comment: wordpress.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.domainname.com
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/wordpress
 <Directory /srv/www/wordpress>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
 <Directory /srv/www/wordpress/wp-content>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /root/cert/domainname.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert/domainname.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /root/cert/ca_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>

Comment: https:www.domainname.com still says The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149724/discussion-between-vrao-and-pataluc).